# Float Field showing more decimal places than field size

Tags: delphi, floating-accuracy, mysql-5.7, delphi-11-alexandria

I am moving from Delphi Seattle 10 with MySQL 4.1 to Delphi Alexandria 11.1 with MySQL 5.7.
After that, I found a problem with fields of type `FLOAT(16,6)`, using the `TFDQuery` component, which brings different results from the database. For example:

=>`TFDQuery`:

```
select ALTURA, LARGURA from tabprodutos (without ";")
ALTURA = 0,0199999995529652
LARGURA = 0,150000005960464

select ALTURA, LARGURA from tabprodutos; (with ";")
ALTURA = 0,02
LARGURA = 0,15
```

=>HeidiSQL or PHPMyAdmin:

```
select ALTURA, LARGURA from tabprodutos (with ";")
select ALTURA, LARGURA from tabprodutos; (without ";")
ALTURA = 0,020000
LARGURA = 0,150000
```

Using the `TFDQuery` component, different results are obtained by writing the script with and without ";", a problem that did not happen in Delphi Seattle. In this example, the value we need and that is recorded in the database is 0.02 and 0.15

I have already verified that for `DECIMAL` fields the problem does not happen, but we would like to keep the `FLOAT` fields and find some other solution, either by changing some parameter of the component, Data Mapping or another procedure that solves this situation.

I know that `FormatFloat` on `FieldEditor` is an option, but it's not easy to change them on the whole system, so would anyone know if there is the best solution?

Comment: `FLOAT(M, D)` does not mean a decimal format that can represent `M` digits. It means a floating-point format with sufficient precision that it can be used to store numbers up to M-significant digits because the original value can be uniquely distinguished—after it is converted to the floating-point format, converting it to decimal with `M` significant digits (i.e., rounding the floating-point number to the nearest `M`-decimal-digit number) reproduces the original value…

Comment: … Issues with the number appearing sometimes as “0,020000” and sometimes as “0,0199999995529652” come from the conversion to decimal, not the stored number.

Comment: Also `FLOAT(M, D)` is non-standard and deprecated in MySQL 8.0.17. It should not be used in new code. `FLOAT(P)` is standard and specifies a number of bits, rather than decimal digits.

Comment: Sorry for the late answering, I've been busy solving some company issues.

Thanks for the reply Eric Postpischil and also to Eirik A. for the editing my post.

I understood the problem of the field type being obsolete, but could anyone tell if for Delphi 11, in TFDQuery components it is correct to use semicolon " ; " and what are the consequences using semicolon?